# Uploading blob with FormData, File content is empty

Tags: ajax, webkit, blob, form-data

I'm trying to upload a blob with FormData on chrome.
I'm building a web app.
A user can create a profile and select an avatar, which is an img tag.
When I'm trying to do an ajax request, I build a canvas with the image and call toDataURL on it.
Then I transform the data into binary content using this function

```
    dataURItoBlob: function(dataURI) {
      var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
      var array = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    }
```

When the blob is created I add it to the formData and send the ajax query (with jquery).
The thing is, the content of the file appears to be empty.

```
 ------WebKitFormBoundarysToAVAYMLPFfJF96
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="avatar.png"
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream


 ------WebKitFormBoundarysToAVAYMLPFfJF96--
```

Using FileReader I do a readAsText on the blob and it actually has content :

```
 �PNG


 IHDR�
 IDATx^���������v�"�`���^[l��N�����׸�k�؁�X�B�[�i�eٜ����yg����E�dF����o~���{�s�sN(�˲�_t�ɤ����݇ns(Z�6ڇ>�O}}��b��l�����ks�̱��r�w�}��{��x<޲}�Q644XNN�;޷�~k7�|��z��V[[�����o�����rss��WTTXII�UWW[^^^��455Yqq���Ը��ߏ>���Xc
 ���s��o��Yg�ew�y�566��...
```

Has anyone already encountered this issue ?
I just don't understand why the query sends an empty file.

Comment: Chrome developer tools doesn't actually show the content of files in form data, did you get an empty file in your server side script?

Comment: I'm not the one developing the server script. I'll ask the server developer but I think you're right. Is there any way to have the files logged in developer tools ? Anyway, can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome developer tools doesn't actually show the content of files in form data, check the sever side to see if the file is indeed empty. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) (a firefox plugin) shows you a portion of file data, you can also use tools like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see http post bodies.

Comment: Also while the blob is data and not (necessarily) a file it will still arrive as file upload server-side. E.g. in PHP expect it as $_FILES entry and not as $_POST entry.
(the combination of this and not seeing it in Chrome dev tools cost me several hours today..)